# Access Python QObject from QML fails to convert on second call

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I am hitting an obscure problem (bug?) with my Python3 QML program.
I implemented a QAbstractListModel with a custom get method to get to the underlying QObject items. The moment I try to get the same Python QObject at two different places in QML I get:

```
TypeError: unable to convert a Python 'QMyItem' object to a C++ 'QObject*' instance
```

The get method looks like this:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, result=QMyItem)
def get(self, row):
    return self._items[row]
```

And the model like this:

```
ComboBox {
    model: mymodel
    textRole: 'name'
    onActivated: mymodel.item = model.get(index)
    onModelChanged: currentIndex = getCurrentIndex(mymodel, mymodel.item)
}
```

The problem is actually unrelated to the way I retrieve the QObject. It really seems to be about the Python to QML conversion. As if the converter keeps a list of already passed references and gets out of sync somehow.

**I now have a minimal sample which shows the error.** Get the source from https://github.com/sturmf/python_samples.git and go into the folder `pyqt_combobox_qabstractlistmodel`. In there start the sample with `python3 main.py`. In the shown ComboBox see that you can select item `three` but item `one` gives you an error on the console. The reason is that item one was already once passed from Python to QML and it doesn't work a second time.

Maybe the converted QObject got somehow garbage collected on the QML side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem was that the QML side garbage collected my objects after I handed them to QML. The reason is that I never set a parent fot this QObjects.